# Concatenation of string with a specific array elements

Tags: php, mysql

the given code below insert data from an array to the mysql table.as its not the full code but what i want to know is available in this code. my question is that there is a field in table named "image_url" but the data in that field only have image name and i want to append http://www.xxxxxx.com at the start of every image name and the replace it with the image name in the field but i dont know how to do that plz help me out

thanks in advance

```
function putTest($t) {

    //$c = connect();

    foreach ($t as $k => $v) {

         $query = "INSERT INTO test (".implode(',',array_keys($v)).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$v)."')";

         //echo "<pre>";

        // echo  $query;
        $r = mysql_query($query);

    }
    //mysql_close($c);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should do what you want:

```
if (isset($v['image_url'])) {
    $v['image_url'] = 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/' . $v['image_url'];
}
```

You can concatenate strings with the dot "[`.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)"!

Answer (score 1):

At first... Is your application protected against [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)? If not you should build two methods/functions like this using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
function sqlSafeKey( $key){
    return '`' . mysql_real_escape_string( $key) . `'`;
}

function sqlSafeValue( $value){
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $value) . "'";
}
```

And than use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to escape your values like this:

```
$keys = array_map( 'sqlSafeKey', array_keys( $v));
$values = array_map( 'sqlSafeValue', $v);
```

About your question... The [matzino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328188/1149736) is correct and whole loop should look like this:

```
function putTest($t) {

    //$c = connect();

    foreach ($t as $k => $v) {
         $v['image_url'] = 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/' . $v['image_url'];
         $keys = array_map( 'sqlSafeKey', array_keys( $v));
         $values = array_map( 'sqlSafeValue', $v);

         $query = "INSERT INTO test (".implode(',', $keys).
                  ") VALUES ('".implode("','",$values)."')";

         //echo "<pre>";

        // echo  $query;
        $r = mysql_query($query);

    }
    //mysql_close($c);
}
```